# How can I customize the look of the notifications - toastr-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, toastr

I'm trying customize the position of the toast.

I tried do that, but it doesn't works:

applications.js

```
//= require jquery
    //= require toastr
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require_tree .

    $(document).ready(function() {


     toastr.options = {
                      "closeButton": false,
                      "debug": false,
                      "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
                      "onclick": null,
                      "showDuration": "300",
                      "hideDuration": "1000",
                      "timeOut": "5000",
                      "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                      "showEasing": "swing",
                      "hideEasing": "linear",
                      "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                      "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
                  }

    });
```

I'm using rails 5, anyone know why it doesnt works?
Tks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you use toastr-rails?

I've tried use that but I can't do it, so now I'm using toastr directly: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Just add in application.js so create a partial like that:

```
<% unless flash.empty? %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <% flash.each do |f| %>
        <% type = f[0].to_s.gsub('alert', 'error').gsub('notice', 'info') %>
        toastr['<%= type %>']('<%= f[1] %>', '', {"closeButton": false, "debug": false, "positionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width", "onclick": null, "showDuration": "300", "hideDuration": "1000", "timeOut": "5000", "extendedTimeOut": "1000", "showEasing": "swing", "hideEasing": "linear", "showMethod": "fadeIn", "hideMethod": "fadeOut" });
    <% end %>
</script>
```

Note that the options are inline on the code.

Comment: Just a note, you need to make sure that this is running after the toastr js and css files have been fully loaded

Answer (score 2):

toastr-rails is outdated now and I strongly suggest adding toastr standalone. If you are using Rails 5+, you can add toastr with yarn:

```
yarn add toastr
```

Of course, you can still download `toastr`, copy and paste into assets too - if you don't have yarn.

then add an helper:

```
module FooHelper
  def toastr_flash_class(type)
    case type
    when "alert"
      "toastr.error"
    when "notice"
      "toastr.success"
    else
      "toastr.info"
    end
  end
end
```

create a partial, for example `_toaster.html.erb`

```
<%= content_tag(:script) do %>
  <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
    <%= toastr_flash_class("#{type}") %>('<%= message %>')
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

call your partial from your layouts, or from your views:

```
<%= render 'layouts/shared/toastr' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this post is kind of old, but in case anyone else stumbles upon it in the future, here is how I got toastr to work using `gem 'toastr-rails'` in my gem file.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require toastr
//= require_tree .

/*global toastr*/
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}
```

For me, I needed to add the `/*global toastr*/` line, because I was getting a console error telling me something along the lines of 'toastr' not being a variable. Then you can use whatever options you want. Don't forget to add  `*= require toastr` to your application.css file, too.

Again, hope this helps someone in the future.